# Where can i find particular version of selenium webdriver supported browsers?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

want to know supported browser's version for selenium Webdriver 2.48.2.0

Comment: http://www.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp can help you.

Comment: Thanks @SanjayBhimani

Answer (score 1):

You can find all supporting environment details in change log. for java below link helps you

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: changelog is something like, what changes went into that webdriver version